# SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas() returns null

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceholder

I'm trying to create a canvas and draw a bitmap to it using the following code:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
InputStream is = assets.open("card_art" + File.separator + "texture.png");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
cardFrontBackingImageView = new SurfaceView(Order.getContext()).getHolder().lockCanvas();
if (cardFrontBackingImageView == null)
{
    Log.e("Canvas creation", "Canvas is null");
}
cardFrontBackingImageView.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, frame, paint);
```

The problem that I'm running into is the one that I'm checking for in the code--lockCanvas() is consistently returning null.  I'm more or less learning this as I go along, so I don't know enough about the SurfaceView, SurfaceHolder, or Canvas to say one way or another what I might be doing wrong; any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas%28%29):

> The returned Canvas can be
>   used to draw into the surface's bitmap. A null is returned if the
>   surface has not been created or otherwise cannot be edited. You will
>   usually need to implement Callback.surfaceCreated to find out when the
>   Surface is available for use.